# Is it possible to query MongoDB without using LINQ in c# program?

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I'm newbie to mongodb. I'm just curious to know the fact about mongodb.

As per my understanding we can create c# program and can query mongodb using LINQ.
But my doubt is, will we able to use any other method to query mongodb via c# other than LINQ.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure you could, but LINQ comes in handy. You could avoid the parts of the fluent interface of the C# driver, but I would advise to use the capabilities the driver offers (including LINQ). Is there any special reason you want to avoid LINQ?

Comment: yes. I'm not good at LINQ. But I'm good at querying the MongoDB using JSON structural type of queries. Thats why I'm hesitating to use LINQ

Answer (score 2):

The C# MongoDB driver uses LINQ the same way entity framework(or whatever they call it nowadays) uses it - it uses the syntax tree of lambda expressions to build proper database commands. In MongoDB's case, these commands are JSON(BSON?), and the C# driver provides ways for you to build these commands directly - see [this example from the tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#findandmodify-method).

The question remains - why don't you want to use LINQ? If it's because your want to build it with old versions of C# and run it on old versions of .NET, than you have another problem - [the driver officially supports only versions 3.5+ of .NET](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/#net-versions-supported).